# Images in CSS Asset in Symfony2

Tags: css, symfony, twig, assets

I have the following problem:

I included the CSS File from fancybox into my **base.html.twig** file:

```
{% block head_style %}
    {% stylesheets
        '../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' filter='cssrewrite'
        '@Bundle/Resources/public/css/site.css' filter='cssrewrite'
        '@Bundle/Resources/public/css/jquery.fancybox.css' filter='cssrewrite'
        %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock head_style %}
```

My directory is the following:

[image: src/Bundle/Resources Directory]

The Problem I'm fancing now is that fancybox can't find the `fancybox_sprite.png`,`fancybox_overlay.png` and `fancybox_loading.gif`.

Here's one of the paths in the `jquery.fancybox.css`:

`#fancybox-loading, .fancybox-close, .fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span {
    background-image: url('../images/fancybox_sprite.png');
}`

Here's the path that the browser is looking for:

`http://project/Resources/public/images/fancybox_sprite.png`

What I also found out is that the `/images` directory won't be loaded into the `/web` dir, but in the `/bundles` dir, though I used `assets:install`, `assets:install --symlink` and `assetic:dump`.

[image: The /web directory]

Why can't the system read the images or why aren't the images loaded into the `/web` dir?

I found a few Questions on SO about this, but neither of them helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the @Bundle notation with cssrewrite, it is known to fail -- [read the second notice here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-css-stylesheets).

You should instead write the relative path to your css files from the web folder. Once you have exported your assets using bin/console assetic:install, your new base.html.twig should read:

```
{% block head_style %}
    {% stylesheets
        '../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' filter='cssrewrite'
        'bundles/something_online/css/site.css' filter='cssrewrite'
        'bundles/something_online/css/jquery.fancybox.css' filter='cssrewrite'
        %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock head_style %}
```